# Настройка FTP чтобы подключатся по внешке

Tags: ftp, ftp-сервер

Я только что понял что мне нужен глобальный FTP-сервер, чтобы я из любой точки планеты смог подрубиться к моему компу, загружать и выгружать на него данные.

Я изучил вопрос и начал работать с FileZilla. Установил, настроил по гайдам с Youtube Kids, и всё казалось бы работает(нет).
Я смог сделать это только с подключением через локальную сеть. Это проблема, ведь у меня на компе стоит VPN, к которому я реально часто подключаюсь(санкции), из-за чего у меня постоянно слетает сервак и если на моём компе работает семья, я тупо не могу контролировать подключен ли впн или нет. Ну это ладно, я смогу решить эту проблему(я чёт отвлёкся извините)

Мой роутер настолько старый, что поддерживает только 4 сервиса по настройке своего домена для подключения DDNS - *DynDNS.org*, *TZO*(я его вообще не нашёл в интернете), *NOIP*(недоступен из-за санкций) и *DNSDynamic.org*(тоже недоступен).

Я хочу попросить помощи или статей, которые хоть частично могут помочь мне разобраться в FTP-сфере.

Изменено:
Я пробовал подключится к noip через VPN. Я всё сделал как положено - установил DUC, зашёл в аккаунт периодически где надо выключал VPN. Хост(как домен так и IP домена) не работают и не подключаются к FileZilla. Мне нужно больше подробностей чтобы настроить как надо:( Помогите

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: я хочу сделать ftp сервер с подключением из любой точки мира. Чтобы от выглядел примерно: romeo558globalftp.myftp.org:21
Но сделать это нужно как минимум через FileZilla и желательно не прибегая к командной строке(хотя это возможно)